# Need help for linking a PDF on page created with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I ask myself the question does an pdf tag exist in rails 4 which can show
an pdf file very simple?

This solution answers me that i need to give the correct route informations:

```
<%= link_to 'Help', public_path%>
```

I already have an pdf file in my project directory **app/assets/public/help.pdf**
and now i wanna have a link with the simple name "Help" to have on my page.

Third edit:

After a nice first answer nothing changes and i get the same error message from rails. What i have to write in the **routes.rb** if i wanna use a link for my pdf file. Does anyone know how can i link an PDF from my own directory!?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Rails, I've never seen a PDF link tag helper.

What you want, is to use [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) in combination with `link_to`

```
<%= link_to 'Help', asset_path('data/help.pdf') %>
#=> <a href="/assets/data/help/pdf">Help</a>
```

If it needs to be absolute, you could always use `asset_url`

```
<%= link_to 'Help', asset_url('data/help.pdf') %>
#=> <a href="http://theurl.com/assets/data/help/pdf">Help</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both of your solutions and get the same answer from rails that i have to give the correct route. On my page i see the link, everything works but if i click the "Help" link i get the message of rails.

Comment: edited - apparently you have to use the subdirectory as well.  the url would be `data/help.pdf` in the methods

Comment: Message of ur edites links: No route matches [GET] "/data/help.pdf". So i have to add something in my routes.rb.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do for linking a document that can be public is I put the document in the public folder in rails and then use this for the path:

`link_to 'Help', root_path << 'TheTitleOfYourPDF.pdf'`

Comment: And then rails gives the information that i need a correct path in my routes.rb. Or does your solution work without any routing?!

Comment: <%= link_to 'Help', root_path << 'help.pdf' %> - right?

Comment: Get this message: No route matches [GET] "/help.pdf" Strange.

Comment: What does tour route file look like? Do you have a root entry in there?

Comment: Nothing special. Nothing pdf related.